# Catch lib (unit testing) and CTest (CMake) integration

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, ctest, catch-unit-test

I'm looking for successful example of Catch [CatchLib](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) integration with CMake test (Ctest) . as I understand this is additional cmake script which has to parse application ouput? 
Did someone already written this? probably shared this?

==================================================

update (solution has been found) :

I've committed [cmake script](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/contrib/ParseAndAddCatchTests.cmake) to CatchLib , for the integration Catch with CTest. this is a simplified version of Fraser99's cmake script [here](https://github.com/Fraser999/MaidSafe/blob/846ce37c23bd86ee261e439919dfd7000a8f9372/cmake_modules/add_catch_tests.cmake)

Comment: There is some discussion about CMake in [Catch's Build System documentation](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/build-systems.md#cmake).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Integrating Catch with CMake is rather simple, as it's a header-only library.

Here's a quick rundown of what you have to do:

You can either assume that the Catch sources are already installed on the build machine or use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html) for fetching them as part of the build process.

In either case, you will end up with the Catch header files in some known directory on your build machine. I would recommend creating an interface target for making this information known to your test executables:

```
add_library(Catch INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(Catch INTERFACE ${YOUR_CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

That way, you can simply specify Catch as a dependency to `target_link_libraries`:

```
add_executable(my_test ${MY_TEST_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(my_test PUBLIC Catch)
```

As usual with CMake, [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_test.html) takes care of introducing the tests to CTest:

```
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME MyAwesomeTest COMMAND my_test)
```

And that's it already. Run `make test` on the built project to run your tests.

I have a [project on Github](https://github.com/ComicSansMS/GhulbusBase/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) that does this if you need to see a complete working example.

*Update for newer versions of Catch:* If you've already upgraded to Catch2, that one comes with its own package config file so you can just integrate it calling [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). This provides [a smoother CMake integration overall](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/cmake-integration.md) and you don't have to start defining your own interface target. While the approach above will still work even with Catch2, I would recommend using `find_package` if your Catch version supports it already.

Comment: but is there a scripts to add ctest tests automatically?

Comment: Only if you write one. How should CMake know which of your executables are the tests?

Comment: https://github.com/Fraser999/MaidSafe/blob/846ce37c23bd86ee261e439919dfd7000a8f9372/cmake_modules/add_catch_tests.cmake

Comment: raise a pull request for Catch lib for auto generating CTest definitions for Catch test cases https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/pull/879 hope this will available after the review

Comment: `catch` has not to be linked... it is a header only library. So why writing a `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: Is it `CMake` (2.6), `Modern CMake` (3.0) or `More Modern CMake` (3.10) ?

Answer (score 6):

Install catch with:

```sh
 $ git clone https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2 <catch_src_dir>
 $ mkdir <catch_bin_dir>
 $ cd <catch_bin_dir>
 $ cmake -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=FALSE <catch_src_dir>
 $ make
 $ make install
```

Then do add the following to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)
```

See [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/979bbf03bb00bc55ca09783791b5091a2247df68/docs/cmake-integration.md).